# vertical-align: middle is not aligning elements in the center

Tags: html, css

Could someone explain what the problem is in the code? No matter what I do, even taking out all the styles I can't align in the middle.

```css
.Div1 {
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 100%;
     width:100%;
     position: relative;
     min-height: 100px;
     background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,113,142,1) 0%, rgba(119,111,111,0.8855917366946778) 80%);
}
.Div2 {
      position: absolute;
      top:75px;
      bottom: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Div1">
  <p>I-BS</p>
  <div class="Div2">
      <p>
          <font size="auto">              <strong>CRONOGRAMA&nbspCLUSTER;&nbsp;&nbs;&nbsp;&nbsp;EMBARCAÇÃO&;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;;SAÍDA </strong>
          </font>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you think is `vertical-align: middle` doing? It is not aligning a text in the vertical center of an element. It is aligning the text in the vertical center of the line-height!

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want aligned where? Are you married to that markup? It's been a long time since I saw <font>

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using flex instead by replacing

```
         vertical-align: middle;
```

with

```
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
```

```css
.Div1 {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     height: 100%;
     width:100%;
     position: relative;
     min-height: 100px;
     background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,113,142,1) 0%, rgba(119,111,111,0.8855917366946778) 80%);
}
.Div2 {
      position: absolute;
      top:75px;
      bottom: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Div1">
  <p>I-BS</p>
  <div class="Div2">
      <p>
          <font size="auto">              <strong>CRONOGRAMA&nbspCLUSTER;&nbsp;&nbs;&nbsp;&nbsp;EMBARCAÇÃO&;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;;SAÍDA </strong>
          </font>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```